# How to enable single touch and disable press to click?

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit.
I used to be a Windows user. The only thing i didn't like about ubuntu i am using is i have to hard press left touchpad with a click sound to click any button. I just want it to work with just a single touch. I am sure there is  some way. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can enable tap to click in the touchpad settings.

Comment: Hello, there is no tap to click in  the settings. thanks.

Comment: so what are your options in the touchpad settings? We need to know more about your hardware. Does `synclient TapButton1=1` in a terminal achieve what you want?

Comment: how do i make it permanent? it doesnot work after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

As described by @danzel, starting your terminal and typing

```
synclient TapButton1=1
```

helps.

But you have to type that every time you restart your machine.

To make it permanent, consult this link: [How can I permanently change touchpad settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382110/how-can-i-permanently-change-touchpad-settings)