# Force change to touchpad parameters

Tags: touchpad, dell

On my Dell Mini 10V with newly installed Lubuntu, the OS is not detecting the touchpad as a 'clickpad', leading to problems with click and drag and other touchpad operations.

If I go to the terminal and type 'synclient ClickPad=1', the touchpad then works correctly until the next time I reboot or restart.

How can I make this change permanent / apply the change automatically each time the machine starts?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/382110/how-can-i-permanently-change-touchpad-settings

Comment: What release of Lubuntu?  (or which desktop, as Session Settings->Autostart varies depending on desktop/release; https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html)

Comment: Lubuntu 16.04 with the default desktop which I think is XFCE? The link to the 'startup' facility looks promising - I'm away from the machine at the moment, will investigate this evening.